# Remove blank space the_title()

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to remove the blank space between the words in the the_titel?

**Example:**

the_title() on one of my posts results in *Merry Christmast*

I want it to result in *merrychristmast*

Which means that I want to remove the blank space and use lowercase only.

Thanks

Edit: I was actually looking for a solution to the the_title-tag not the wp_title-tag. Sorry..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Doing it for `wp_title();`

I combined those two answers posted by Anthony and rzetterberg.
Use [`str_replace();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). It's faster for trivial replacements than [RegEx](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). And if you add the necessary arguments to your [`wp_title();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) we'll end up like this. Please note, that you'll have to add the [`strtolower();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function so that your title is displayed in lower case only.

```
<?php
    echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', wp_title('', false)));
?>
```

---

### Doing it for `the_title();`

It's quite the same technique I posted earlier. You'll just have to change the arguments for [`the_title($before, $after, $echo);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

```
<?php
    echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', the_title('', '', false)));
?>
```

*Note:* Instead of using `the_title('', '', false)` you could prepend it with a [`get_`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title). It does the same and fits your needs better.

```
<?php
    echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', get_the_title()));
?>
```

Comment: Your code works excellent for wp_title. My question was wrong: I was actually looking for a solution on how to do this on the_title-tag. Sorry.. When I change wp_title to the_title it returns _About me_. Do I have to change something else?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

get title -> remove white spaces  (preg_replace) -> to lower case (strtolower)

```
<?php echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', wp_title("",false))); ?>
```

Comment: [`wp_title();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) echos the title by default. `str_replace()` is faster than `preg_replace()`.

Comment: sure str_replace is faster but it does not handle  tabs and other crappy white spaces which would be disturbing if you like to use the result as anchor or something

Comment: Yes, I thougt about that too. And used this way first. But the I dicovered, that `wp_title()` strips all `\s` down to one single `' '`. Also, you won't need the `+` in `/\s+/`, because RegEx will replace all `\s` in both cases.

Comment: Your code works excellent for wp_title. My question was wrong: I was actually looking for a solution on how to do this on the_title-tag. Sorry.. When I change wp_title to the_title it returns About me. Do I have to change something else?

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to retrieve the value and remove the spaces yourself.

Like so:

```
$title = wp_title("", false);
```

[Read more about the arguments for wp_title here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title)